# How to specify the Redirect URI for React Native Bare workflow

Tags: android, react-native, auth0

I've just started building a React Native mobile application with Bare workflow(not using Expo framework).
I have successfully integrated the login and logout system on my app with react-native-auth0 dependency. However, I am struggling with API Authorization to get the token for the authenticated users in order to control the access to each end point.

I am following Authorization Code Flow with PKCE based on the Auth0 documentation. I've got almost everything working fine except the redirect uri which was mentioned earlier on the title.

I tried to use the `expo-auth-session` dependency to specify the uri manually like below.

```
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
    native: `${REDIRECT_URI}`,
    useProxy,
});

const params = {
    audience: `${AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE}`,
    scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: `${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}`,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    code_challenge: `${code_challenge}`,
    code_challenge_method: 'S256',
    state: `${state}`
};
```

However, it returns the error message saying

> Error: No default return URL could be found. If you're using the bare workflow, please provide `options.returnUrl`.
> getDefaultReturnUrl@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:179940:24
> startAsync$@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:177411:84

I have checked my uri with `npx uri-scheme list`.
at the moment, I've got one `${applicationId}://`.
Would this be the equivalent to the redirect_uri, wouldn't it?

I've also have checked [Auth0.Android](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Android).
However, this one must be related to Android Native App development?!
Anyway, anyone who has used the same architecture before? Where I can specify the Redirect URI for Android application built with React Native?
I think the AuthSession API is not supported in Bare workflow. Even though the documentation emphasised, it also articulates the walkthrough for the bare workflow, I gave it a shot. But, it's not working and thrown an error.

I believe this should be done in a native way?!? Java?? I am struggling to find the solution and not even sure where to look at. I would really appreciate your help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I’m really not familiar with React Native (nor with mobile actually), but I do know a few things about OAuth and OIDC, and I used Auth0 in the past, so here a few ideas, hopefully helpful.

> I have checked my uri with npx uri-scheme list. at the moment, I've got one ${applicationId}://. Would this be the equivalent to the redirect_uri, wouldn't it?

According to Auth0 documentation, the callback URL (i.e. the redirect URL to the local device) should look like `{YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}://${YOUR_AUTH0_APP_NAME}.auth0.com/android/{YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}/callback`
So my understanding is that `${applicationId}://` is not equivalent to the redirect URL, but only its prefix.

Have you tried using `${applicationId}://{YOUR_AUTH0_APP_NAME}.auth0.com/android/${applicationId}/callback`
(replacing `${YOUR_AUTH0_APP_NAME}` with the actual value of your Auth0 project name) ?

Comment: Hi Sebastien! Thank you for ur answer.The more I spend my time to investigate this issue, I may have to drop the Auth0 which seems not a quite great choice along with Expo. I couldn't find many usecases and many uncertain aspects of the two tech stacks. Moreover, with my lack of knowledges in authentication and native development, couldn't find returnUrl after all(even though I successfully get the code after running a simple proxy server) in the bare mode. So I am back to the managed mode again. haha but, again as I mentioned, I think they are incompatible as expo doesnt support Auth0 greatly

Comment: I’m not familiar with Expo to comment this, but in a nutshell, to make it work on mobile, you need your application to be able to "read" the redirected URL, e..g when an URL like `{applicationId}://anything` is opened, it should be opened by your app.
This redirectURL is where the Identity Provider (e.g. Auth0) gives back the auth code. Then the client (you app) can query Auth0 (with the PKCE code) to finally get the auth token.
This flow will always be the same for OpenID Connect (with Auth0 or other providers)

Comment: This is how the vulnerable "public" side (user auth+web page) never carries the full identity or access token, only an auth code which can be used one on a secure channel to finally get the token your code will be able to use on behalf of the end-user to make calls (or to gather identity information about them)
Tl:DR: the redirectURL must always be provided, and must be one of the URL allowed in the "Allowed Callback URLs" settings for your Auth0 app. (This allow-list must contain the _exact_ URL : no wildcard, full path)

Comment: yeah when it comes to getting an authorization code from a proxy server was successful. However, I couldn't get my head around with the returnUrl in the bare workflow. I suspect it could be something to do with DeepLinking in Android or something else. As I do not have much experiences with native mobile development and couldn't find much useful information online, I had to give up with the bare workflow. now I am back to the managed work flow. If it was a web, I could easily get the URL parameter.

Comment: But, as I am working on the mobile, there are too many uncertainties and I've nearly come to the conclusion myself that RN alone isn't good enough to build a native application. I have learned so much about authentication and authorization from this experience, tho. haha

Comment: another constraint I have realized that I only have learned how to decode jwt token on the backend and verify the permissions from Auth0. For the mobile application, I can only use response_type: 'code' to get the authorization code as you may know. I think I am going to take a break for awhile. probably it's not my range that I can solely work on my own any time soon.

Comment: I have got the code from callback and saw it on my mobile chrome browser. So, I expected that expo authsession class would return the value from response.param. But, it didn't work. Once I logged in, the browser closed and the app was just infinitely loading and nothing happened.